# Manage multiple YAML extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the Home Assistant extension installed in VSCode but also want to use the ESPHome extension, both of these are for YAML files.

I need a way of telling VSCode which extension to use.

I wonder if it is possible to configure VSCode to use a specific extension in a specified folder tree or else to put something in the YAML file itself so the extension can recognise that it should be effective for that YAML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you want to select installed extensions for in your case; YAML files.

VSCode :

- Home Assistant extension
- ESPHome extension

Via '**exentension**' > '**dis/enabled [workspace]**', you can arrange it.

Workspace recommended extensions#

A good set of extensions can make working with a particular workspace or programming language more productive and you'd often like to share this list with your team or colleagues. You can create a recommended list of extensions for a workspace with the Extensions: Configure Recommended Extensions (Workspace) command.

[image: exentension dis/enabled [workspace]]

Extra information SEE https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19792

This option was moved into **Command pallette** (F1)

Comment: Extra information : SEE https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19792 about an issue on mac